# Can browser run CommonJS perfectly?

Tags: javascript, browser, browserify, commonjs

I have a stupid question.

Since there is many tools that can load CommonJS in the browser(like Browserify).

Does that means all NodeJS's code can be run in browser?

Does that means browser can run as a server?

I know this must be wrong,i just don't know where.

Comment: CommonJS is only a way to load modules, it doesn't allow you to run arbitrary code. If you want to use a Node.js specific thing, then *most likely* you need Node.js. For example you can't really get file system access in the browser *because* the browser is isolating your code from interacting with the current system in this way.

Comment: Thx, i think i get it